# Nested for loop inside do while to keep player's turns in order

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, do-while

This is a beginning attempt to create a turn counter for a simple turn-based game.  Although it's currently an infinite loop, I'm curious if there's a better or more elegant way to do what I want to do - keep players turns in order throughout a complete game.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int i;     // player turn counter
        int j = 6; // number of players created + 1

        do {
            for (i=1; i < j; i++){
                System.out.println("Player " + i);  // just for visualization
            }
        }while (true);
    }
}
```

I'm extremely new with java. I have found that basic for loops need +1 to avoid counting -1 lower.

My while condition will be a check for a winner, say:

```
while(winner == false)
```

or

```
while(!winner)
```

Comment: Actually, `while (!winner)`. You definitely don't want `while(winner = false)`, since `=` is the assignment operator.

Comment: `=` is assignment operator. Use `==` for comparison.

Comment: I edited.  I'm not THAT new, I didn't catch it before hitting submit.  Thanks @khelwood

Comment: You need `i <= j` if you want the 6th player to have a turn.

Comment: I did that recently and it didn't give me the outcome I wanted.  I just tried again and it worked.  thanks @4castle

Comment: Wait a second, what you want to do is to create an order of players and then update that order when one player changes it's initiative? Go with a sorted list and use a single outer bubble sort iteration when a value is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method seems to be the best case scenario right now.
Other methods involve using arrays which will just complicate things here.
Though to save the nested loop, you can just add the condition of `!winner` to the for loop

```
for (i=1; i < j && winner == false; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Player " + i);
        if(i==j)
            i=1;
    }
```

this will work as good and will save the other loop.

Comment: I'm not to arrays yet.  I added the `!winner` to my code snip and edited the question above also.  ty @Yashovardhan

Comment: Note that now you don't require the outer do while loop anymore.

Comment: You can just add an if condition to check when i == j then set it back to 1

Comment: My first go was 216 characters, including that if statement you added
My second was 215 characters,
and yours is 170 characters.

Awesome, @Yashovardhan

Answer (score 0):

That is completely fine, just a few observations `while(winner == false)` as a single `=` means assignment and `==` means comparison.